# How to check if ClassType inherits from java.util.Collection in JDI?

Tags: java, debugging, jvmti, jdi

I can get all the interfaces of a `ClassType` with `allInterfaces()` but this results in many JDWP calls to the debuggee which is slow. Another approach would be to check this:

```java
Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(classType)
```

but the method `isAssignableFrom()` is in `java.lang.Class` and so I have to call this method with `invokeMethod` like this:

```java
javaLangClassReference.invokeMethod(threadRef, isAssignableFromMethod,
                        Arrays.asList(myClassType),
                        ObjectReference.INVOKE_SINGLE_THREADED);
```

But there are two issues here:

1. `classType` cannot be used as parameter for the method call, it is not a `Value`
2. How do I provide the `java.util.Collection` as a param to the Method `(Arrays.asList(myClassType, ...))`?

Also, is there a simpler way to check if a given `ClassType` is a `java.util.Collection`?

Comment: isAssignableFrom is in java.lang.Class. It is not in java.lang.Object.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, you are right, it was my mistake. Updated.

Comment: You can use [`classObject()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/ReferenceType.html#classObject()) to convert a `ReferenceType` to the corresponding `ObjectReference`/`Value`.

Comment: @Holger, thank you, so then I will have `javaUtilCollectionRef.classObject()`, and then I will just call  `javaUtilCollectionRef.classObject().invokeMethod(...,Arrays.asList(myClassRef.classObject()),...)`, is that correct?

Comment: Seems to be the only way